# Fragments overlaps another fragment when clicking on floating action button

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-navigation

I am trying to open another fragment inside a fragment. However, when I click on the fab, I see the layout has been replaced but the previous fragment still stays there. I try to replace the whole layout of the profile XML but it doesn't replace properly. I tried to call it as an intent but I can't call fragment as an activity.

The Fragment:

```
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        ArrayList<ProfileItem> profileList = new ArrayList<>();

        fab = root.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        container.clearDisappearingChildren();

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AddProfileFragment fragment = new AddProfileFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.profile_container, fragment);
                transaction.commit();


            }
        });
```

The XML file I want to replace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.profile.ProfileFragment"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/profile_container" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
        android:text="@string/profiles"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.024"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.097"
        android:layout_below="@+id/up_toolbar"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/profileRecView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_profile"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_profile"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/primary_green"
        android:contentDescription="Submit"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The home activity where I access the profile fragment:

```
  public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.nav_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_data, R.id.navigation_profile)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);


    }
}
```

Layout of the add profile that's overlapping:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".ui.addProfile.AddProfileFragment">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextHumidityLow"
        android:layout_width="60sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView14"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextHumidityHigh"
        android:layout_width="60sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView12"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="25sp"
        android:layout_height="25sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_thermostat"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView13"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextCO2High"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_carbon_humidity" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
        android:text="Humidity threshold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextCO2Low" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
        android:text="Low:"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
        android:text="High:"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editTextHumidityLow"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
        android:text="CO2 threshold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTemperatureLow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Low:"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextCO2Low"
        android:layout_width="60sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="High:"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editTextCO2Low"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextCO2High"

        android:layout_width="60sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="25sp"
        android:layout_height="25sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_thermostat"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTemperatureHigh"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_iwwa_co2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
        android:text="Create a new profile"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
        android:text="Name of the profile:"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextProfileName"
        android:layout_width="170sp"
        android:layout_height="45sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
        android:text="Temperature threshold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Low:"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="High:"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editTextTemperatureLow"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTemperatureLow"
        android:layout_width="60sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTemperatureHigh"
        android:layout_width="60sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="25sp"
        android:layout_height="25sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_thermostat"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextProfileName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_save_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/primary_green"
        android:text="Save"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextHumidityHigh" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/faded_gray"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_save_profile"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextHumidityHigh" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Would be nice if you share how did you do the transaction for the current fragment (first fragment) in your activity.

Comment: The first fragment transaction is handled by the AppBarConfiguration. There's nothing that I coded. Would you still like to see the code.

Comment: Can you share the activity layout, and how did you make the first fragment transaction

Answer (score 1):

```
AddProfileFragment fragment = new AddProfileFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
fragment.setArguments(args);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.profile_container, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```

You are trying to replace fragment in a container with id `R.id.profile_container`, and actually this id is not for a container in the activity layout, but it's for the root layout of the current fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.profile.ProfileFragment"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/profile_container"
    >
....
```

To fix this, you need to have some container/placeholder ViewGroup in the activity that hosts your shared fragment, and replace the `profile_container` in below script with that id

```
transaction.replace(R.id.profile_container, fragment);
```

**UPDATE**

> The first fragment transaction is handled by the AppBarConfiguration

Now you are using [Navigation Architecture components](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) for fragment transaction, and this is done with the fist fragment transaction, but you used the `FragmentTransaction` for the second fragment, although the [`navController`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController) is the responsible for fragment transaction in Navigation Architecture Components.

So, to solve you need to use the `navController` for the second transaction:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    ArrayList<ProfileItem> profileList = new ArrayList<>();

    fab = root.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    container.clearDisappearingChildren();

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            
            NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment); 
            if (navHostFragment != null) {
                NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
                navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_profile, args);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand the placeholder. If I click on the profile fragment and click on the fab button, then the profile fragment is supposed to be a parent of the layout that's called for the fab button or no?

Comment: @Spreceriany Just noticed that you updated the question.. Please see the updated answer in *UPDATE* section

Comment: Thank you for your time to update the code. However, you mentioned that I am using the Navigation component. I checked some videos and as you say, the component is handling the switching of fragments. On the onClick method I used: Navigation.findNavController(root).navigate(R.id.navigateToProfilesFragment); This seems to work as I need. I forgot to use the navigation layout the android studio provides.

Comment: @Spreceinay if Zain has answered your question you should mark his answer as the correct one. Zain took the time to help and gave you an awesome answer, at the very least Zain deserves an upvote.